# Proof with disjunctive conclusion

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm after a natural deduction proof of the following sequent:

(P & Q) → R : (P → R) ∨ (Q → R)

The textbook I'm using says there is a 24 line proof, but the shortest I've managed is 29 lines. I've provided my proof below. Can anyone find the 24 line proof?

(In general, the proofs I'm overshooting on all seem to have disjunctive conclusions - so I'm wondering if there's some trick I'm missing for generating disjunctions.)

Thanks in advance!

---

Here's my 29 liner. Basically, I show ~(P → R) → (Q → R) [line 19] then get the conclusion from there by reductio.

EDIT 1: I've added dependency numbers in curly brackets {}, to indicate the premises and assumptions each line depends on.

EDIT 2: As Bram28 helpfully points out, my proof system is Lemmon-style (in case other people find this thread useful).

1. (P & Q) → R        `Premise` {1}
2. ~(P → R)                 `Assume for conditional proof`{2}
3. Q                        `Assume for conditional proof`{3}
4. ~P                       `Assume for reductio`{4}
5. P                        `Assume for comditional proof`{5}
6. ~R                       `Assume for reductio`{6}
7. P & ~R                   `5,6 &-Introduction`{5,6}
8. P                        `7 &-Elimination`{5,6}
9. P & ~P                   `4,8 &-Introduction`{4,5,6}
10. ~~R                     `6,9 reductio`{4,5}
11. R                       `10 double negation elimination`{4,5}
12. P → R                   `5,11 conditional proof`{4}
13. (P → R) & ~(P → R)      `2,12 &-Introduction`{2,4}
14. ~~P                     `4,13 reductio`{2}
15. P                       `14 double negation elimination`{2}
16. P & Q                   `3,15 &-Introduction`{2,3}
17. R                       `1,16 modus ponens`{1,2,3}
18. Q → R                   `3,17 conditional proof`{1,2}
19. ~(P → R) → (Q → R)      `2,18 conditional proof`{1}
20. ~((P → R) ∨ (Q → R))    `Assume for reductio`{20}
21. P → R                   `Assume for reductio`{21}
22. (P → R) ∨ (Q → R)       `21 v-Introduction`{21}
23. ((P → R) ∨ (Q → R)) & ~((P → R) ∨ (Q → R))       `20,22 &I`{20,21}
24. ~(P → R)                `21,23 reductio`{20}
25. (Q → R)                 `19,24 modus ponens`{1,20}
26. (P → R) ∨ (Q → R)       `25 v-Introduction`{1,20}
27. ((P → R) ∨ (Q → R)) & ~((P → R) ∨ (Q → R))        `20,26 &I`{1,20}
28. ~~((P → R) ∨ (Q → R))   `20,27 reductio`{1}
29. (P → R) ∨ (Q → R)       `28 double negation elimination`{1}

Comment: The number of lines in a proof is heavily dependent on the axiom system applied, and a lot of your references like `25 vI` and `20,27 RAA` are non-standard, so it is hard for us to determine what axiom system you are using.

Comment: I've changed the references, so hopefully those are more comprehensible now. As for the axiom system, how do I find that out and communicate it on here? I'm using Paul Tomassi's textbook, "Logic". It allows the rules: & introduction and elimination, V introduction and elimination, modus ponens and modus tollens  [→], double negation introduction and elimination. For the ↔, you can introduce P↔Q from the two lines P→Q and Q→P, or eliminate it by replacing with ((P→Q) & (Q→P)). Does that help? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and: conditional proof, reductio.

Comment: In some systems: if $\neg \phi$ leads to a contradiction, then you can infer $\phi$ ... so you wouldn't have to first infer $\neg \neg \phi$ and then get $\phi$. Is that maybe something you can do in your system?

Comment: No, the book doesn't allow that. It says I have to infer ¬¬ϕ first and then get ϕ by double negation elimination.

Comment: steps 7 and 8 seem useless...

Comment: Hmm, those are there so that the P in step 8 is derived from the ~R in step 6. Step 9 is then dependent on the ~R in 6, so I can get the reductio in step 10. I'm pretty sure that's required in Tomassi's system, but maybe this is another respect in which it's idiosyncratic. Sorry - I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: But 9 follows already from 4 and 5.

Comment: Yes, it does - but can I reject the assumption in 6 if I skip 7 and 8? The thought is that if I derive 9 from 4 and 5 alone, 6 is not implicated in the contradiction and so I can't reject it. Does that make sense?

Comment: To clarify that, I've added dependency numbers in curly brackets {} to indicate the premises or assumptions each line relies on. Step 5 relies only on itself [ {5} ], whereas 8 relies on 5 and 6 [ {5,6} ]. That's the extra thing I thought I was getting via steps 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it in 21 steps ... the proofs by contradiction work a little different in the system I use, which is why those steps don't check out, but I think the proof below conforms to your rules:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! That comes out as 23 lines in my system, which is better than I asked for :D

To explain the extra two lines: My system doesn't allow the reductio at line 11, because line 5 (which is being reductio-ed) didn't play any role in the derivation of line 10. I need to add two somewhat silly looking lines to remedy that (e.g. the way I did it in lines 7 and 8 of my original attempt).

Comment: @Dlogic Ah!  OK, so you must be using a system where you have a set of statements as an explicit  'support-base' or 'assumption-base' in every line of the proof .. since I didn't see those listed in your proof I figured it was more of a nested system like I use. But yes, in some of those systems you indeed have to do some 'extra' lines to get the right statements into your assumption base ... I noticed your lines 7 and 8 so I should have known!  Good to know I still beat the book's 24 line proof :)   Now you do realize in logic it really doesn't matter how many lines you take, right?

Comment: @Dlogic P.s. your system is known as a 'Lemmon'-style proof system. What I used is called a 'Fitch'-style proof system.

Comment: Thanks! I'll bear that in mind in future.

Comment: @Dlogic I just realized I forgot: you will no doubt have noticed the main way in which I shortened the proof: I immediately assumed the negarion of the disjunction to be proven. You said you often 'overshoot' proofs where you have to prove a disjunction, and were looking for some tricks, and in my experience if you have to prove disjunction, and you don't have some other disjunction to start out with, it is typically a good idea to immediately do a proof by contradiction.